# Change material of mesh difference edges

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I have a subtraction of two meshes, for the sake of clarity, let's pretend I'm subtracting a sphere from a cube. I would like to change the material on the faces of the cube that were generated by the subtraction. I thought I could use the `Intersecting edges` output from the `Mesh boolean` node, but it doesn't change anything

[image: Image of the node setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome Alessandro Di Cicco, the out-put Intersecting Edges of the `Mesh Boolean` select the contour not the surface. So to be able to do what you want you have to use a `Geometry Proximity` node and Less Than of a `Math` node like this:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Have a nice day.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!